# tell tcpdump to not include the port numbers in the output

Tags: linux, networking, port, network-monitoring, tcpdump

how can tell tcpdump to not include the port numbers in the output? Right now it includes the resolved IP + resolved port. I just need the resolved IP address (hostnames)

Comment: Did you read the man page? and did you try -qt?

Comment: -qt gives me `IP 68.142.93.173.80 > 10.0.0.2.51155: tcp 1448` which still has the port numbers on the end of the fields (the `.80` and `.51155`)

Comment: @mossy -qt doesn't do what i am asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want a list of ip addresses?

If so, this will extract the to ip addresses

```
sudo tcpdump -n | cut -d ' ' -f 5 | awk -F. '{ if (NF == 2) { print $1 } else { print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }}'
```

this will extract the from ip addresses

```
sudo tcpdump -n  | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | awk -F. '{ if (NF == 2) { print $1 } else { print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 }}'
```

ipv6 safe.

If you really just want everything other then the ports, this will do the trick (requires gawk)

```
sudo tcpdump | gawk '{
split($3, from, ".");
$3 = from[1]
for (i=2; i<length(from); i++) {
    $3 = $3 "." from[i] 
}

split($5, to, ".");
$5 = to[1]
for (i=2; i<length(to); i++) {
    $5 = $5 "." to[i] 
}

print
}'
```

Comment: this doesn't produce any result......

Comment: What os/version of tcpdump?

Are you sure you're sending enough packets to get awk to flush it's buffers?

Comment: tcpdump -h
tcpdump version 4.2.1
libpcap version 1.1.1
 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: i get:awk: line 4: illegal reference to array from
awk: line 10: illegal reference to array to

Comment: Sorry, this required GNU's awk (gawk). If you install that package and use gawk instead of awk in the command line, it works as expected